# Press F to place monument

Tags: mass-effect-2

I am playing the 'Normandy Crash Site' DLC for Mass Effect 2, and have been tasked with placing a monument in memory of the members of the Normandy SR-1 that died in the crash.

In various locations which are scattered around the map (like the remainder of the original CIC or the helm of the ship), a prompt appears on screen stating "Press F to place monument", but regardless of how much I mash the F key while changing my positioning in these areas nothing seems to happen.

What am I missing? How do I place the monument to the Normandy SR-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an oversight in the design of the on screen prompt, which doesn't take into consideration that you might want to change your key bindings. In the end I had to use the key binding for "Melee attack", which I presume is normally bound to <kbd>F</kbd> by default.

This resulted in the monument to the fallen Normandy SR-1 being placed.

[image]

Comment: yeah, none of the tooltips in the game reflect your bindings. It's an unfortunate truth.

Comment: yeah I just spotted another one - on the planet Aria sends you to in order to collect crates I got a "Press F to end mission"... I don't even have F bound to anything! /sigh